# 10 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texmaker, memory

can someone explain me the message that appears in PDF statistics log file, if it is important how to avoid it ?

> 10 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 with texmaker.

**PS:** Compilation proceeded perfectly, output is fine.

Comment: It's just statistics about memory usage. Nothing strange at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is just a report on the usage of memory during a run of TeX. Here's a sample of what I got with a document:

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1035 strings out of 493054
 13273 string characters out of 6134760
 70364 words of memory out of 5000000
 4626 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4548 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,4n,18p,779b,174s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

In the old days when computer memory was scarce, it was important to keep memory usage under control: too many labels or macro definitions could mean exhausting memory and impossibility to process a document.

In the eighties of last century, 5000000 words of memory were not even a dream. Divide by a factor 100 or more and the figure would be more realistic. Using more than twenty fonts (rather than the 9000 currently provided for by TeX Live) was very near to the maximum.

When LaTeX2e was released, the main TeX implementation for MS-DOS (or OS/2), emTeX, had very little memory allocated, in order to comply with the operating system limitations. LaTeX documents with more than 100 labels or so were at risk of memory exhaustion. To the contrary, OzTeX for Mac OS already allowed for increasing memory parameters (up to what was allowed by the operating system, of course).

The `pdftex` engine adds some reports of its own; something like

```
PDF statistics:
 36 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 25 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

that help in checking we're not stretching it to the limit. Using up 10 words of extra memory doesn't seem a big deal.

While you can suppress the report issued by LaTeX (the first set of data) by saying

```
\tracingstats=0
```

somewhere in the document (best at the top), the final statistics issued by `pdftex` cannot be suppressed, as far as I know.

Comment: "Using up 10 words of extra memory doesn't seem a big deal" when does it becomes a big deal and how to avoid it since document is getting bigger

Comment: @guest00 A 195 page document of mine, with several fonts and some graphics says `20629 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 20736 (max. 10000000)`, which should mean that 20736 were allocated, but only 20269 were actually used, out of 10 million maximum. I guess that `pdftex` starts with 10000, and then allocates more when need arises. I wouldn't worry until I reach something around 9 million.